# What is the "right" way to use a GUID as the key in std::hash_map

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, stl

I want to say

```
std::hash_map<GUID, int> foo;
```

I believe to do this I must create an

```
bool operator < (const GUID &guid1, const GUID &guid2);
std::size_t hash_value(GUID const &b);
```

what is the proper way to compare GUIDs? (memcmp?)  - what is the proper way to generate a hash?

it'd be great if someone would flesh out these two functions,  I've read dozens of posts that do everything but give the final clue :-)

Comment: If it's useful, there is the [`IsEqualGUID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680575%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function that you can use if you don't like calling `memcmp` directly (that's all the above function does anyway).

Comment: There is no such thing as `std::hash_map`. Not in standard C++ anyway. What are you asking about?

Answer (score 6):

From [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373931%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it seems that:

```
typedef struct _GUID {
  DWORD Data1;
  WORD  Data2;
  WORD  Data3;
  BYTE  Data4[8];
} GUID;
```

There are probably several possibilities

**Building your own**

For comparison I'd go item by item

```
bool operator < (const GUID &guid1, const GUID &guid2) {
    if(guid1.Data1!=guid2.Data1) {
        return guid1.Data1 < guid2.Data1;
    }
    if(guid1.Data2!=guid2.Data2) {
        return guid1.Data2 < guid2.Data2;
    }
    if(guid1.Data3!=guid2.Data3) {
        return guid1.Data3 < guid2.Data3;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++) {
        if(guid1.Data4[i]!=guid2.Data4[i]) {
            return guid1.Data4[i] < guid2.Data4[i];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

For hashing... I'd go for the [UuidHash](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function (note that GUID is a form of UUID as indicated in the [UUID definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379358%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

**Going back to strings**

Use the [StringFromCLSID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa912019.aspx) to get a string from the GUIDs... once you have string, you have all the operators.

... this is probably more expensive.

Comment: thanks @jsantander - do you see anything wrong with using memcmp?

return memcmp(&guid1, &guid2, sizeof(GUID)) < 0;

Comment: @stuck might work... but if you're paranoid, the struct layout could leave alignment empty spaces (not sure if that's the case) that would have undefined values that you would be using in the comparison.

Comment: There is actually no need for less than comparison for hash maps, only for tree (regular, ordered) maps.

Answer (score 5):

There is no std::hash_map in the C++ library and stdext::hash_map is an obsolete class (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/0d462wfh.aspx).

To use a GUID in a std::unordered_map:

```
#include <climits>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

// Adopted from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373931%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
typedef struct _GUID
{
    std::uint32_t Data1;
    std::uint16_t Data2;
    std::uint16_t Data3;
    std::uint8_t  Data4[8];
} GUID;

// Ensure it has 128 bits
static_assert(sizeof(_GUID) == 128/CHAR_BIT, "GUID");

// The compare operator is required by std::unordered_map
inline bool operator == (const GUID& a, const GUID& b) {
    return std::memcmp(&a, &b, sizeof(GUID)) == 0;
}

// A wrapper to create a GUID
inline GUID make_guid() {
    // Should return the value of some library function. 
    return GUID();
}

// Specialize std::hash
namespace std {
    template<> struct hash<GUID>
    {
        size_t operator()(const GUID& guid) const noexcept {
            const std::uint64_t* p = reinterpret_cast<const std::uint64_t*>(&guid);
            std::hash<std::uint64_t> hash;
            return hash(p[0]) ^ hash(p[1]);
        }
    };
}

// Usage
int main(void) {
    typedef std::unordered_map<GUID, int> map_type;
    map_type m;
    m.insert(map_type::value_type(make_guid(), 0));
    m.insert(map_type::value_type(make_guid(), 1));
    m.insert(map_type::value_type(make_guid(), 2));
}
```

Comment: You should really static assert that the alignment of GUID is >= std::uint64_t. e.g.`#include <type_traits> static_assert(std::alignment_of<GUID>::value >= std::alignment_of<std::uint64_t>::value, "")`.  For me this assertion fails. GUID has the same alignment as std::uint32_t

Answer (score 4):

Since GUID is just POD, should be able to just do this:

```
namespace std
{
    template<> struct hash<GUID> : public std::_Bitwise_hash<GUID>
    {
    };
}
```

Comment: TIL POD means "Plain Old Data"

Comment: `test.cpp:6:61: error: expected template-name before '<' token
     template<> struct hash<GUID> : public std::_Bitwise_hash<GUID> {};`

Answer (score 1):

For a Windows implementation I would simply head for [::UuidHash()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windows/desktop/aa379343(v=vs.85).aspx). So the hash function will become like so:

```
#include <rpc.h>

namespace std
{
    template<> struct hash<GUID>
    {
        size_t operator()(const GUID &Value) const
        {
            RPC_STATUS status = RPC_S_OK;
            return ::UuidHash(&const_cast<GUID&>(Value), &status);
        }
    };
}
```

Remarks:

- Interestingly ::UuidHash() returns just an unsigned short, but this seems to be sufficient to hash GUIDs (why else should MS have done that?).
- For an unordered_map/unordered_set no less(), operator<(), etc. is required, just a functor to calculate the hash. Internally the hashes are compared (to locate the containing bucket), not the elements, that's why.
- If a comparison is needed for other purposes use [::UuidCompare()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windows/desktop/aa379201(v=vs.85).aspx) and burry it in overloaded operators for syntactic sugar (still waiting for the space ship operator to materialize...).
- For a hash function that is suitable for a hash based STL container it is not required to have as little collisions as possible. More important is a *fast* hash function. If you have acceptably little collisions it will just lead to buckets with more than one value stored but things stay operable. So the (possibly suboptimal?) unsigned short returned by ::UuidHash() should be no issue.

Answer (score 0):

what type is your GUID? consider this piece of code below:

```
struct MyCompare : binary_function<SomeClass, SomeClass, bool>
{
    //constructor
    MyCompare(int (SomeClass::*p)() const, int (SomeClass::*p2)() const) : pointer(p), pointer2(p2) {}

    //comparison functor

    bool operator < (SomeClass const& left, SomeClass const& right)
    {
        if ((left.*pointer)() != (right.*pointer)())
        {
            return less<int>()((left.*pointer)(), (right.*pointer)());
        }
        else
        {
            return less<int>()((left.*pointer2)(), (right.*pointer2)());
        }
    }
    private:
    int (SomeClass::*pointer)() const;
    int (SomeClass::*pointer2)() const;
};
```

That is for a composite key of 2 fields of type int. Sort first pointer then stable sort second pointer. Code may not run first try but you get the idea.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, given GUID is a general concept, you should be specifying which GUID class you're talking about.  I'm going to guess that it's [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373931%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  Microsoft Windows one, since you tag `visual-c++`....

A quick 'net search for "hash GUID" shows that Microsoft provide a recommended hash, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.gethashcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1).  It sounds like it has major flaws, described [here](http://csharptest.net/1258/understanding-the-pitfalls-of-using-system-guid-with-sequential-values/).

If for some reason you can't or don't want to use that, consider the data members:

```
typedef struct _GUID {
  DWORD Data1;
  WORD  Data2;
  WORD  Data3;
  BYTE  Data4[8];
} GUID;
```

These non-C++-Standard types are documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383751%28VS.85%29.aspx).
You can get a reasonable 32-bit hash doing something like:

```
DWORD hash(const GUID& g)
{
    return std::hash(g.Data1 ^
                     ((g.Data2 << 16) | g.Data3) ^
                     *(DWORD*)(g.Data4) ^
                     *(DWORD*)(g.Data4 + 4);
}
```

To understand this - it's effectively taking the fields like this:

```
              [16 bits here]         [16 bits here]
      g.Data1=0101100101010010:1001010101001010
      g.Data2=1011110101001001 1011101010101010=g.Data3
g.Data4[0..3]=1010111010101010:0011101001000101
g.Data3[4..7]=1101111010100100:1010100011010110
         hash=1001010000010101:1011110101110001
```

From top to bottom, it's xoring all the bits together, so the final hash line above is 1 if there's an odd number of 1 bits above it.  If you want a stronger hash, you could bitshift a single contributing value both left and right by e.g. 3-16 bits, xoring both, or use a `hash_combine()` function (google it!).

You do not need an `operator<` for a hash map (you only need one for a sorted binary tree - i.e. `std::map`), but do need to be able to compare for equivalence... i.e. `operator==`.  You can indeed use memcpy to do the comparison - given the field sizes and order it's clear the structure won't need padding, so all the bits are meaningful for the comparison.  You'll have to use `memcmp`, compare every character separately, or use more type casting, so I'd just run with a single `memcmp`....

Comment: the hash MSFT is providing is managed,  if I don't provide operator< I get a linker error

Comment: @stuck: sure... if you're not writing managed code, I've provided an alternative - "some reason you can't...use that".  Re `operator<` - it shouldn't be needed by the hash map - it may be being called from some other code.